# How to make FloatingActionButton Draggable?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

The fab hides some of my app's content and it to be dragabble. I have implemented OnDragListener method on the fab but still nothing seem to be happening in my activity_list.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    fab =  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createPopDialog();

        }
    });

    fab.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    dX = event.getX();
                    dY = event.getY();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    fab.setX(dX-fab.getWidth()/2);
                    fab.setY(dY-fab.getHeight()/2);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping floaingActionButton and override onTouch method.